# How do I install Drupal In Ubuntu?

Tags: installation

I want to install Drupal in Ubuntu. How can I do it?

Comment: Hello, Anto Aravinth and welcome on _Drupal Answers_. This question is too generic to be acceptable. If you have something specific that you don't understand about installing Drupal, then you can edit your question.

Comment: The question is not too generic. If it is believed that the question is offtopic here, it should at least be migrated to askubuntu.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this walkthrough](http://drupal.org/node/812470) to be helpful when I was first setting up Drupal on my Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 2):

It is this easy to install

```
sudo apt-get install drupal
```

Comment: This is not a good approach. This will install whatever version of Drupal is in the Ubuntu packaging system, and this could well be out of date. Drupal security updates are released regularly, so better to be secure and get Drupal straight from Drupal.org.

Comment: That is true, but once you have Drupal set up, you will be informed of this and can change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just start software center and search for Drupal. Then you just install the Drupal package.

If you have a server without running x-server, you need to use the command line, which is like on all Debian based system "sudo apt-get install Drupal".

However, Ubuntu normally does not have a very updated version of Drupal in the archives. It may be good if you need a stable version or if you test, but not if you require to have newer versions or security updates very fast.

In all other cases, you are better off to follow the normal Drupal installation instruction for any Linux system.